# Modifying content through jQuery after an AJAX post

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use jQuery to modify some content that comes through from an AJAX but it can't seem to access the content for some reason. I'm still pretty new at jQuery so I'm not sure where it's going wrong yet and was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction.

All of the code is located on GitHub here https://github.com/Ryan-Myers/WordPress-Survey-Plugin/blob/master/survey-js.php

But the relevant code is as follows (This is part of a wordpress plugin btw):

```js
//Add a new question to the passed survey
function add_question(survey_id) {
    var data = {
        action: 'survey_add_question_ajax',
        security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("survey_add_question_nonce"); ?>',
        survey: survey_id
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        jQuery('#survey-admin-page').html(response);
        jQuery('#survey-questions-table').slideUp();
        jQuery('#survey-add-question').slideDown();
    });

    //FAILS HERE
    jQuery('#survey-add-question').ready(function(){
        //Default to hiding the question setup until they select a question type.
        jQuery('#questionsetup').hide();
        jQuery('#save_question').attr('onclick', 'submit_question('+survey_id+')');

        //Testing to see if it will return a usable value, which it doesn't.
        alert(jQuery('#save_question').attr('onclick'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$.ready doesn't work like that: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

> The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted.

You typically use it to know when the DOM is ready and then start executing code that is dependent on the DOM.

You can either add the block of code that isn't working to the callback of $.post, after the slideDown, or you can add a callback to slideDown, that will fire after the slideDown is complete: http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: +1 for the callback to slideDown, I think that is what is needed here.

Comment: I'm tired after a long night and you sound well informed. I'm just going to to say you're right and verify in the morning. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Is #save_question loaded dynamically ? Is that why your using  jQuery('#survey-add-question').ready().

for example

```
$('#save_question').live("click", function() {
   submit_question(survey_id);
});
```

If so you may want to look at [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

If you just want to wait for the post to fininsh before running your code put your code inside the jQuery.post function

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
       // code in here will be called once the response is returned from AJAX

    });
```